# If an IPv4-only VPS hosts a VPN that assigns IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to clients, can IPv6 traffic be routed through IPv4?

Tags: networking, ipv6, strongswan

I know very little about IPv6.

Many privacy-focused hosting providers don’t support IPv6 yet.

If I host a strongSwan VPN on an IPv4-only VPS, can IPv6 traffic be routed through IPv4?

Comment: You can tunnel IPv6 packets through IPv4 to their final destination that can be an IPv6 or IPv4 host. It is irrelevant if this happens in a VPN scenario or not.

Comment: @Overmind Thanks for the feedback. How is this achieved on Debian?

Comment: I've put all info into an answer as this is a useful-for-the-future thing.

Comment: @Overmind Thanks! Will try this out shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of routing, not of VPN.

You can tunnel IPv6 packets through IPv4 to their final destination that can be an IPv6 or IPv4 host. It is irrelevant if this happens in a VPN scenario or not.

Check some basic Debian how-to [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6) and a practical example of IPv6 tunneling through IPv4 [here](https://shorewall.org/6to4.htm).

The logic of it can be studied from a [CISCO perspective](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6/25156-ipv6tunnel.html) also, which helps other general scenarios.

Make sure that when you implement this while using VPN all routing and network settings correspond to your needs and there should be no trouble.

Comment: Hey, I explored 6to4 and, apparently, this strategy is subject to many [shortcomings](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7526#section-3). Among other things, I am experiencing a lot of packet loss. Also, it involves routing encapsulated IPv6 packets through relay servers which (in the context of user privacy) creates a potential honeypot. Am I missing something?